# Inconsistent behavior between str_split and strsplit

Tags: string, r, split

The documentation for `str_split` in the *stringr* package states that for the pattern argument:

> If "" splits into individual characters.

which suggests it behaves the same as `strsplit` in this regard. However,

```
library(stringr)
str_split("abcab","")
[[1]]
[1] ""  "a" "b" "c" "a" "b"
```

with a leading empty string. This compares with,

```
strsplit("abcab","")
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "b"
```

Leading empty strings seems to be normal behavior when splitting on non-empty strings,

```
strsplit("abcab","ab")
[[1]]
[1] ""  "c"
```

but even then, `str_split` generates an 'extra' trailing empty string:

```
str_split("abcab","ab")
[[1]]
[1] ""  "c" ""
```

Is this discrepancy a bug, feature, an error in the documentation or just a different notion of what's 'expected behavior'?

Comment: Probably would be better to file a bug report with the developer than ask on stackoverflow...

Comment: Sorry @hadley, I basically never think I've found a bug. I have very low self esteem.

Comment: It is probably not a bug, but a different interpretation of *splitting a string by the given delimiter*. (A different notion of what's 'expected behavior'.)

If you split the string **abcab** by  the delimiter **ab**, then I expect the result to be `​` and `c` and `​`. However, not all programmers interpret that on the same way.

Comment: Getting here 11 years later it looks like the behaviour is similar now - bug resolved

Answer (score 4):

If you use commas as delimiters, the "expected" (your mileage may vary) result is more obvious:

```
# expect "" "2" "3" "4" ""

strsplit(",2,3,4,", ",")
# [[1]]
# [1] ""  "2" "3" "4"

str_split(",2,3,4,", ",")
# [[1]]
# [1] ""  "2" "3" "4" ""
```

If I have `n` commas then I expect `(n+1)` elements to be returned.  So I prefer the results from `str_split`.  However, I wouldn't necessarily call this a bug in `strsplit`, since in performs as advertised:

> (from ?strplit) Note that this means that if there is a match at the beginning of
>        a (non-empty) string, the first element of the output is ‘""’, but
>        if there is a match at the end of the string, the output is the
>        same as with the match removed.

`""` is trickier, as there is no way to count the number of times `""` appears in a string.  Therefore treating it as a special case seems justified.

> (from ?str_split) If ‘""’ splits into individual characters.

Based on this I suggest you have found a bug and should take hadley's advice and report it!

Comment: I did report it, seeing as how hadley is the author of this function. ;)